# series of windows open with colorbox resize to fit content

Tags: php, jquery, html

folderI have a series of different size tables that need to open from each other and resize depending on content, I have the first window open fine, the second window doesn't resize I think it's because it opens from an image with an rather than a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no need for an anchor `<a href>` in order to trigger colorBox

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".what-ever-class-selector").colorbox();
});
```

where any element with class="what-ever-class-selector" will trigger via jQuery selector query.

Comment: Hi, I think I worked out what was going on, because essentailly each window was opening in the same ajax container it was staying the same height as it was first told to on opening. I added styling to each stage telling colorbox to change height and it worked. Thanks for your help, it put me on the right track to solving the problem.